# Trying to create a future value calculator with shiny app in R and get error: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

This is the code I have on my server file:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$P = renderText(input$Slider1)
  output$n = renderText(input$numeric1)
  output$r = renderText(input$numeric2/100)

futureValue <- reactive({
   principal <- output$P
   numberOfPeriods <- output$n
   rate <- output$r
   fvalue <- principal*(((1+rate)^numberOfPeriods-1)/rate)
   return(fvalue)
   })

output$fv <- renderText(futureValue)

})
```

Code for main panel on UI File:

```
sidebarPanel(
h4("Select Monthly Investment Amount:"),
sliderInput("Slider1","Select Monthly Investment Amount:", 100, 1000, 
100),    
numericInput("numeric1", "Select Number of Payments:", value = 12, min 
= 6, max = 60, step = 1),
numericInput("numeric2", "Select Interest Rate Percentage:", value = 
3.0, min = 0.1, max = 5.0, step = 0.1)  

mainPanel
(
    h4("Monthly Investment Amount:"),
    textOutput("P"),

    h4("Number of Periods:"),
    textOutput("n"),

    h4("Interest Rate:"),
    textOutput("r"), 

    h4("Under the given circumstances, the future value of your 
    investment is:"),

    textOutput("fv")
)
```

Everything works except for the last part where I'm performing the calculations for future value. Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You seriously need to use better variable names. I have no idea what `p` is.

Comment: @AustinWBryan these are standard names in financial maths. P=principal, n=number of periods, r=interest rate, fv=future value

Comment: `btn` is very standard to mean `button`, yet I almost never see people do using `btn`, I see them using `button`, because it's easier to read, even if you know what `btn` means. My rule of them is if you have to explain to someone what the name of the variable is, either using comments or what have you, then it's a bad name. It should be self explainatory. Also, do you need to change `output$r` to be `output$rate` now?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on variable-naming. `output.$r` is basically what you want to name the output so when you want to render it in the UI.r file you can call that name. When you create a variable with that output, it doesn't necessarily have to have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi reactivs are functions not variables

```
output$fv <- renderText(futureValue() )
```

and change the reactive function like this

```
futureValue <- reactive({ 
  principal <- input$Slider1     
  numberOfPeriods <- input$numeric1 
 rate <- input$numric2 
 fvalue <-principal*(((1+rate)^numberOfPeriods-1)/rate) 
 return(fvalue) })
```

should solve it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, @Bertil. i did try that as it was suggested in other questions posted. However, when I do as you suggest, the message changes to `Error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed`. I also tried `output$fv <- renderText({futureValue()})` as it has been suggested as well and I get the same error as with your suggestion.

Comment: You need to change all your textOutputs to textInput in the ui

Comment: The input part is actually in the sidebar panel. I'll edit the question so it's included there.

Comment: Well as the error message says you can`t access outputs in the server they are there to link results to the ui. You need to access the inputs with the corresponding values just like you did in the render functions.

Comment: Ok, will try that in a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Changed my answer to include how you could do that

Comment: If it helped you please accept the answer so that other people with the same problem quickly can find the solution